# R forecasting - issue with dates in prediction

Tags: r

I'm doing a forecast in R using the forecast package.

I have a time series with daily data (download the .CSV [here](http://pastebin.com/mu160syb)):

```
library(forecast)
data <- read.csv('daily_electricity.csv')
time_series <- ts(data$value, start=c(2007,1,1), frequency=365.25)
fit <- stlf(time_series) # uses STL decomposition
plot(fit)
forecast(fit, h=365)
```

But when I issue the last `forecast` command to get predictions for the next 365 days, the output not only skips days - but the values aren't in regular date format:

```
2012.687 2480489
2012.689 2411931
2012.692 2582997
2012.695 2190245
2012.697 2603242
2012.700 2413211
```

How can I get forecasts for the next 365 days, with each value formatted with the correct date, with no missing days?

Comment: are those not just decimal years? What does the `forecast` help have to say?

Comment: the forecast help doesn't mention anything.  If those were decimal years, they don't end up on whole days.  Ie 0.687 * 365 = 250.755.  Is that the 250th day of the year, or the 251st?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is convert the dates (which are brought in as row numbers) to an actual column.

```
setDT(fit, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
```

Then you can use decimal_date() to convert to proper format:

```
fit$dates <- as.Date(date_decimal(as.numeric(fit$rn)))
```